# How to return a value in a vector by reference?

Tags: c++, reference

I am trying to return a `Vertex &`, here's the code:

```
Vertex& Graph::getVertex(std::string v) {         // gets the vertex 
     for (std::vector<Vertex>::iterator it = vertices.begin(); it != vertices.end(); it++) {
        if ((it->getName()).compare(v) == 0)
          return it;  // if strings are the same return vertex
     }
     exit(1);
}
```

The problem is that `getVertex` is flagged as incompatible and `it` in the return is flagged as a reference of type `Vertex &` (non-const qualified) cannot be initialized with a value with of type `std::vector` ...
How would I fix these errors?

Comment: Thanks, also I had to change the name of the getVertex to getRefVertex and everything should be working, I think there was a clash since I had two getVertex one returning a reference and the other the object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're trying to return the *iterator*, not what the iterator points to. So you need to return `*it`.